# TCanvas constructor doesn't create TFont object

Tags: inno-setup

I want to create a Canvas object at runtime in the code section of Inno Script.
Here's the extract of code:

```
[CODE]
var
 Mask : TCanvas;

procedure CreateMask
begin
  Mask:=Tcanvas.create
  if Assigned(Mask.Font) then
    Mask.Font.Color:=50
  else
    MsgBox('Font is nil', mbInformation, MB_OK);
 end;
 .
 .
```

The result is windows that displays the message: "Font is nil"

The problem is Font property of Canvas is read only so that's not possible to instantiate  it with Mask.Font:=TFont.Create

So the question is: how to create a TCanvas object at runtime with associated objects TFont, TPen, TBrush instantiated properly?

Comment: You are not supposed to create a `TCanvas` nor `TFont` istances.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback TLama. My goal was to try and use Canvas object to set objects of a device context. I understand I will have to use Windows API  for that.

Comment: If you want to draw some graphics, you can use `TBitmapImage`. If you're going to draw onto an existing Windows control, you will need much more than just calling Windows API functions. That would require to intercept that control's window proc and draw what you want in a response to the `WM_PAINT` message.

Comment: My goal is actually to draw onto an existing window. I'd like to create an outline effect around labels when the mouse points a label.

Comment: Then you will need to intercept `TNewStaticText`'s window proc.

Comment: Thanks so much TLama, I'm gonna dig around that